# Lucene_36 - Cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, lucene, stop-words

I am trying to use Lucene in my program to remove Stop Words and implement Stemming?  However, when I try and import `Lucene_36` like so...

```
public String removeStopWords(){
    StandardAnalyzer analyser = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
     Analyzer analyzer = new StopAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36,new StringReader(GetTweets.tweetContent));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenStream, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
    CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
```

It returns the error underneath the `Lucene_36` sections of code saying `Lucene_36 - Cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

Any help?

Thanks guys

Comment: Which version jar are you using?

Comment: @satya -  I have imported several of Lucene 5.4.1's JARs.  Particularly, the analyser, core, demo, queries, query parser ones.

Comment: But `Version.LUCENE_36` means 3.6 version. Here you suppose to use some `Version.LUCENE_5*` not exactly. Check the 5.4 API for this.

Comment: Look here , you should use `LUCENE_5_4_1` : https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html

Comment: @satya - but even if I do `Version.LUCENE_CURRENT` this does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a lot changes to the API since version 3.6.  Backwards compatibility for Lucene 3.6 was dropped in version 5.0, and aside from that, none of these constructors take `Version` arguments anymore.

I'm not quite sure how you are using the analyzers and such you've constructed here, but here's a quick rewrite that should, at least, compile:

```
public String removeStopWords(){
    StandardAnalyzer analyser = new StandardAnalyzer();
    Analyzer analyzer = new StopAnalyzer();
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setReader(new StringReader(GetTweets.tweetContent));
    TokenStream tokenStream = tokenizer;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
    CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I do Version.LUCENE_CURRENT this does not work either

Why because its deprecated from the 5.4.1 API.

```
static Version  LUCENE_CURRENT
```

> Deprecated. Use [LATEST](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/index.html)

```
public static final Version LATEST
```

ex:

```
Version.LATEST
```

or

```
Version.LUCENE_5_4_1
```

Comment: It being deprecated wouldn't prevent it working, it just isn't advisable.  Functionally, using `LUCENE_CURRENT` is exactly the same as using `LATEST`.  At any rate, none of the methods in the code provided even take a `Version` argument anymore.

Comment: @femtoRgon, I just read the API but I didn't work on it. In the API itself they are suggesting to use `LATEST`. Any way Thanks.. I learned some new.